# How do I override the HTML output of a theme function?

Tags: theming

Let say we have theme function in module A `theme_super_a()`, this function returning some HTML. I want to write function in my own module (let's call it B) where I can get output of `theme_super_a()` manipulate it and return back to Drupal theme system. How can I do it?

Notice that I'm not interested in overriding whole theme with `hook_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry)`.

Comment: If you're not willing to use the function provided for doing EXACTLY what you want to do, then you're not going to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the whole theme function in your own module.
Because the override is done from a module level, not the theme, you will probably need `hook_theme_registry_alter` to change the theme function settings for that specific `hook_theme` component.